# Looping and scraping financial tickers

Tags: python, json, loops, web-scraping

I can't seem to get this done. I need to loop through multiple URLs in a CSV file but it is not working. Each line in csv has a URL, as in 'https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/AAPL.OQ', changing the final ticker. Here's my code.

```
import requests
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd

stocks_arr =[]
pfolio_file= open("URLTickers.csv", "r")
for line in pfolio_file:
    indv_stock_arr = line.strip().split(',')
    stocks_arr.append(indv_stock_arr)
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}
    jsonData = requests.get(line, headers=headers).json()

print(stocks_arr)

for stock in stocks_arr:
    data = {
        'Ticker': [],
        'Beta': [],
        'DY': [],
        'VOL': [],
        'P/L': [],
        'Cresc5A': [],
        'LPA': [],
        'VPA': [],
        'Ultimo': [],
      }

    ticker = jsonData['market_data']['ric']
    beta = jsonData['market_data']['beta']
    DY = jsonData['market_data']['current_dividend_yield_ttm']
    VOL = jsonData['market_data']['share_volume_3m']
    PL = jsonData['market_data']['pe_normalized_annual']
    cresc5a = jsonData['market_data']['eps_growth_5y']
    LPA = jsonData['market_data']['eps_normalized_annual']
    VPA = jsonData['market_data']['book_value_share_quarterly']
    Ultimo = jsonData['market_data']['last']

    data['Ticker'].append(ticker)
    data['Beta'].append(beta)
    data['DY'].append(DY)
    data['VOL'].append(VOL)
    data['P/L'].append(PL)
    data['Cresc5A'].append(cresc5a)
    data['LPA'].append(LPA)
    data['VPA'].append(VPA)
    data['Ultimo'].append(Ultimo)

table = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Ticker', 'Beta', 'DY', 'VOL', 'P/L', 'Cresc5A', 'LPA', 'VPA', 'Ultimo'])
table.index = table.index + 1
table.to_csv('CompleteData.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
print(table)
```

This is the response:

```
ticker = jsonData['market_data']['ric']
Key Error: 'ric'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using wrong key.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Which key? Can you show me what I should change?

Answer (score 1):

The issue *seems* to be the response you get from the request. The GET request succeeds but the JSON response doesn't have the nested key you're asking it.

```
ticker = jsonData['market_data']['ric']
```

Make sure the JSON structure is static. Sometimes certain key don't appear in certain conditions. So, unless the key `ric` doesn't exist at all, you may need to add a condition before trying to parse the response.
Such as

```py
if 'ric' not in jsonData['market_data']:
    print(f"Incomplete data. Skipping.")
```

Bonus points if you use exception handling.

Comment: I'm not sure if I followed what you said. There is a `ric` in every URL.

Comment: @DiegoLins That's what I meant, yes, at least one URL does not return a JSON with the structure you expect. Please, share the CSV you're using or, in case that's not possible, debug the code further with the `if` statement I posted (remember to include output of what URL had to be skipped).

Comment: This is the output: 
`if 'ric' no in jsonData['market_data']:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @DiegoLins Sorry, my bad. Fixed `no` into `not`.